# Converting a do-while loop into a while loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

My code is this I just want to convert my do-while loop into a for loop or a while loop how do I do that. The point of the program is to reverse the input word. like if you put in abc it would output as cba.

```
int main()
{

    while (i < --length - 1);
        cout << word << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: but is there no other way to change it, by just modifying the above program?

Comment: Then you will need to explain the specific restrictions because there are many ways to reverse a string, some simpler than others. The simplest of course is just to use reverse function.

Comment: Your do-while loop is wrong because it will break for an empty string. It should probably be `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`

Comment: my do-while loop is correct, it runs perfectly for the required task. There is no restriction, they have just asked to write a code, with a do-while, while, for loop. while accomplishing the same task. *3 separate codes

Comment: @user3467226: Assuming that the requirement is not "reverse any string", but instead "reverse some strings", then yes, your loop is fine.

Comment: Change `cin >> word;` to `getline(cin, word);` and enter an empty line and it no longer works. Why not write code that continues to work with changes elsewhere?

Comment: Why did you edit your question to not make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is this, which doesn't bother doing anything with strings of size 0 or 1:

```
int length = word.length();
if (length > 1)
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    while (i < length)
    {
        ch = word[i];
        word[i] = word[length - 1];
        word[length - 1] = ch;
        i++;
        length--;
    }
}
```

For version:

```
int length = word.length();
if (length > 1)
{
    char ch;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++, length--)
    {
        ch = word[i];
        word[i] = word[length - 1];
        word[length - 1] = ch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way to convert a while loop into a for loop takes this form:

```
// While loop
int i = 0;
while( i < n ) {
    // Amazing things happen here
    i++;
}

// Equivalent for loop
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    // Amazing things still happen here
}
```

Therefore, applied to your code it would look something like:

```
char ch = word[i];
word[i] = word[length - 1];
word[length - 1] = ch;

for( int i = 0, length = word.length(); i < --length - 1; i++ ) {
    char ch = word[i];
    word[i] = word[length - 1];
    word[length - 1] = ch;
}
```

Note that since the do-while loop executes the body of the loop before testing, I had to put one copy of the loop body out front. To avoid having to update two different copies of the code, you may want to extract the loop body into a function, which is then called in front of the loop and in the loop body.

And for a while loop version:

```
int i = 0, length = word.length();

char ch = word[i];
word[i] = word[length - 1];
word[length - 1] = ch;

while( ++i < --length ) {
    char ch = word[i];
    word[i] = word[length - 1];
    word[length - 1] = ch;
}
```

Comment: i tried running your code, and it didn't seem to work.But what you are saying is that the code i have in the body of my do-while loop should come before the while loop if i were to convert it into a while loop.

Comment: Yes. The only difference between the while loop and the do-while loop is that the do-while loop tests the condition after it executes the loop body once.

Comment: Note that `i < --length - 1` is the same as (barring overflow, which isn't a problem for meet-in-the-middle) `i + 1 < --length`.  Also you want to increment anyway, so `while (++i < --length)`

Comment: @APerson: It wasn't a bug to begin with, this is just a shorter way to write it.  But now you do have a bug, because `i` is incremented twice per iteration.